# Move multiple sprites together as a cluster in libgdx

Tags: android, animation, libgdx, sprite

I have say N individual sprites. When user move them closer they snap together and become a cluster. Cluster can have sprites anywhere between 2 to n. If user touches on any cluster member sprite, entire cluster must be moved together.

Currently my problem is I can do this with lot of calculations when a move happen to organization and move them all to gather. When a new member joins the cluster I have to reorganize all again. But is there a better way to merge/groups sprites to gather? So I can perform move and rotation as a single unit.  See the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest seems to be to use [Scene2d Group](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.html) instance to keep sprites together and a simple [Scene2d Image](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html) to handle single sprite. Unfortunately you would need to rewrite your game screen but I believe that it's worth.

Here take a lok at [Scene2d description](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) and then at [Scene2d tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-1.aspx)